# Checking if filter string will return results

Tags: angular

I have this `*ngIf` statement and I would like to check for the opposite of the condition to display a specified message but I am having some trouble with how to get the opposite of my filtered result. I would like to show a message based on if the user entered a filter string that didn't correspond with any items in the roster filter list.

Here is my condition statement:

```html
*ngIf="rosterFilter: filterstring"
```

What would be the opposite of this?

Answer (score 0):

Opposite of the condition achived by `!` :

```
*ngIf="!(rosterFilter: filterstring)"
```

Comment: for some reason when i have tried this i would get: `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors` in my console when i run the page.

Comment: I am still getting an error: `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 15 in [!(rosterFilter: filterstring)] ...`

Comment: Will you please create a plunker for this ?